# Having trouble formatting printf correctly in C++

Tags: c++, c, string-formatting, riscv

Although this is C++, I am using `printf` because the lab I am doing calls for it.
I'm in a predicament where I cannot figure out how to properly format the following:

```
printf("     %-6s  x%d, x%d // %08x\n", lookup(inst.opc_keys, inst.opc, inst.opc_vals).c_str(), inst.rd, inst.imm, list[i]);
```

The variables are arbitrary for the purposes of keeping this simple, but I am trying to format this so that the `// %08x` is always the same amount of space from the rest of the statement.

An ideal example output would be:

```
addi     x4, x4, -12       // 0xfffff
addi     x4, x4, 2000      // 0xffffa
```

But the way I have it currently, it would be printed like so:

```
addi     x4, x4, -12 // 0xfffff
addi     x4, x4, 20000 // 0xffffa
```

Once again, the instructitons/numbers here are arbitrary--just using this as an example.
How do I format this correctly with `printf`? (i.e. no iostream)

Comment: Which columns are supposed to be left-justified, and which are right-justified?

Comment: Note that `x%d` looks strange: `x` before a decimal.  I suspect you want `x%x`.

Comment: `"     %-6s  x%d, %d // %08x\n"` uses widths of 6 and 8.  Do the same with `%d`.  Try `"%5d"`, `"%05d"`, `"% 5d"`, `"%-5d"`, etc .

Comment: @RobertHarvey the instruction and it’s parameters are supposed to be left justified by 25 characters.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica that’s intentional actually :) it prints x# (which represents a register in RISC-V)

Comment: OK.  In order for this question to be fully specified, we would need to know: 1.  The width of each column, and 2.  Whether each column is left or right justified.  Assuming you want things to line up (which is what your example appears to suggest), your data currently has *four columns.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes it has 4 columns currently. But I want it to be like it has 2 if that makes sense. Ideally, the entire string (save for the comment) would be left justified 25 characters, then the comment would just be added on after.

Comment: @EthanR Is there some samples can be reproduced by others?

Comment: If you want the whole string to be 25 chars wide, use `sprintf` to first create a string and then do `printf("%25s // %08x", ...)`

Answer (score 2):

`x%d, %-15d` to right pad the last integer with a container of 15 characters. This will ensure even spaces.

```c
printf("     %-6s  x%d, %-15d // %08x\n", lookup(inst.opc_keys, inst.opc, inst.opc_vals).c_str(), inst.rd, inst.imm, list[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by writing the first part to a temporary array:

```
char tmp[30];
sprintf(tmp, "%6s  x%d, x%d, %d", 
        lookup(inst.opc_keys, inst.opc,inst.opc_vals).c_str(), inst.rd, inst.imm, other);
```

Then print that string left justified followed by the comment:

```
printf("%-25s // %08x\n", tmp, list[i]);
```